# How can I make a Python 3.x program allow the user control what the program does?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, multiple-choice

The program is supposed to do the described functions on the numbers given, but I get an error after I give the second number.

**code**

```
num1=int(input("Give me a number: "))
num2=int(input("Give me another number: "))

add=int(("For addition, press [1]."))
time.sleep(2)
sub=int(print("For subtraction, press [2]."))
time.sleep(2)
div=int(("For division, press [3]."))
time.sleep(2)
multi=int(("For multiplication, press [4]."))
time.sleep(2)
print("Please input an option and press [RETURN].")

if input == 1:
    ans=num1+num2
if input == 2:
    ans=num1+num2
```

Any ideas on how I can improve on my code?

Comment: `add=int(("For addition, press [1]."))` is trying to convert a string to an int and then store that in a variable. Perhaps you meant `print` and not `int`? Otherwise, it's going to give you an error about converting a string to an int. Also, `if input == 1` is not referencing any variables you've created, so there's no way I can see that it would ever work.

Comment: @RandomDavis yes, I meant to print it, and have the [1][2][3][4] options activate the addition/subtraction/multiplication/division aspects of the code, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

More simplified version:

```
print "Basic calculator"

num1=int(input("Enter number 1: "))
num2=int(input("Enter the other number: "))

choice=int(input("For addition, press [1].\n"
    "For subtraction, press [2].\n"
    "....\n"
    "Please input the operation and press [RETURN]."))
time.sleep(2)

if choice == 1:
    ans=num1+num2
elif choice == 2:
    ans=num1-num2
    ...

print "Answer is {}".format(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an **input** replace with this:

```py
add = int(input("For addition, press [1]. "))
```

Comment: This isn't a solution to the problem. OP meant to print those lines, not get input from them.

Comment: @RandomDavis I wanted *both*

Comment: @WhiteTail You only wanted to get one input and print 4 lines, right? What you're implying is that you wanted to get 4 inputs, one for each printed line. But you are only checking one value at the end, which implies you only want to get one input (besides the first two numbers). Besides, Abijith Mg's answer seems to be a good solution.